# How to send email to mailing list in excel using gmail

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, vba, gmail

Currently, when I type an email into excel it becomes a link.  When I click on this link, the default browser opens a new gmail tab logged into whichever gmail account I am currently logged into, and opens a compose email to the address of the link.

What I want to know is if it is possible to have this same behavior except that the compose email is addressed to multiple emails based on a mailing list defined in excel.

Here are some things I could do without but would like the solution to do in addition to the behavior described above:

- Populate the subject based on values in the excel document
- Specify which emails would be cc'd and who would be the primary recipient
- Pre-populate the email with some specified text
- Attach a file to the email

I realize that this question may be too broad for an exact solution, but if this is the case, I would be happy for someone to just say if it is possible (without 100s of hrs), point me in the right direction, and guess at ~ how long it would take to figure out and implement. I am open to any way of doing this, and am proficient with VBA.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm.

Methinks you're looking at "on-click" (aka change event) style VBA actions. http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/event.htm has some examples, including some related to email.

The difficult thing here is, I think, the attach file part and I'm not sure how that might be achieved.  There is some discussion of that here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675414/add-attachement-to-outlook-with-varying-file-names